# $p$-groups with isomorphic subgroup lattices

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-groups

Given two non-abelian finite p-groups $P_1$ and $P_2$ of the same order that are not isomorphic.

> Can $P_1$ and $P_2$ have isomorphic subgroup lattices?

(I'm not experienced with group theory, sorry in case this is not appropriate for MO).

Comment: An example with $|P_i| = 3^5$ is given by Jack Schmidt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14732/17384).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *yes*. You can find references at page 277 of the book

Roland Schmidt: *Subgroup lattices of groups*, De Gruyter Expositions in Mathematics **14**, Berlin: Walter de Gruyter. xv, 572 p. (1994). [ZBL0843.20003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0843.20003).

> [image]